# ng-template if doesn't work with method http

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 form. I use ng-template to change from Form A to Form B after click Next button and the Next button will call some method in my service. But **case 1**  doesn't work

In file my-app.component.html

```
    <ng-template [ngIf]="showFormA" [ngIfElse]="anotherForm">
        <div class="form-group">
               ....
        </div>
         <button (click)="onClick()">Next</button>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #anotherForm >
        <div class="form-group">
               ABC
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

I have 2 cases with in file my-app.component.ts

**case 1: It doesn't work in the first time click button** (second time work)

I call some method in my service, that return http.post()

```
onClick() {
   // method: Observable<any>       
    this.service
        .method()
        .subscribe((_) => {
            this.showFormA= false;

        });
}
```

**case 2: It work**

```
onClick() {
    const source = of(1);
    source.subscribe((_) => {
        this.showFormA= false;
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no `btnNextClick` in provided `html`. Can you create a demo code on stackblitz.com ?

Comment: sorry my bad. I edited

Comment: Do you get any message in dev console on first click ? if so, let us know its details

Comment: My service return status code = 200 in first click and second click. when I debug the response I received is null.

Comment: Do you get any message in dev console on first click ? can you check this after 1st click.